# How to calculate sum on a datable column using linq with a where clause?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm just getting stated using linq and I'd like to be able to sum a column in a datatable using a where clause. I can do it on the whole datatable but I have no clue how it works with a where clause.

How would I get the sum where the "State" column = "TN"?

```
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test_Linq
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = null;

            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("State");
            dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(int));
            dt.Rows.Add("TN", 1);
            dt.Rows.Add("TN", 10);
            dt.Rows.Add("FL", 5);

            //this returns 16 - I want it to return 11 for State="TN"
            var sum = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Amount")); 

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `Where` before the `Sum`:

```cs
var sum = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => x.Field<string>("State") == "TN")
            .Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Amount"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like:

```
var sum = dt.AsEnumerable()
          .Where(x => x.Field<string>("State")== "TN")
          .Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Amount"));
```